# Puzzling.SE homed chat-rooms are "insecure"

Tags: bug

Using the https:// URL for any of Puzzling.SE's chat rooms gives a security warning.

For example, in Firefox:
[image: yellow "warning" icon on Secure lock-icon, and "not secure" detail]
(Chrome isn't quite as in-your-face with it, but if you check the "View site information" $\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{\sf{\tiny~\small i\tiny~}}$ it also tells you that "Your connection to this site is not fully secure".)

A quick check shows that amongst all the https:// Media objects there is one that is using the insecure http:// URL:   http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/puzzling/img/bg_pattern.png?v=1 :
[image: Page Info - Media tab]

This background-overlay seems to be pulled in from the style sheet at
URL=https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.puzzling.stackexchange.com.css?v=25d69e3b8357

I assume this inclusion of an insecure element on a secure page is unintentional, so posting this as a [bug](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).  P.SE folks, if you can confirm seeing this as well, it might not be a bad idea to say so here.

Answer (score 3):

See [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

> 11. (Planning required) `chat.stackoverflow.com`, `chat.stackexchange.com`, and `chat.meta.stackexchange.com`

It hasn't yet been completed.

Also:

> ### Update 2017-05-22
>
> [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) is now `https://`. I've written up a lot of what it took to get here [in a blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/).
>   Next up is chat and then `https`-only cookies. We'll be ramping up HSTS `max-age` directives as we go. I'll continue to update this post as we deploy new bits.

Comment: Oh, stop making sense. ;)  Thanks for the reminder, I knew this and had cleverly forgotten it.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, this issue seems to be fixed.  Huzzah!

Leaving this open (for now) in case the problem comes back, as I've seen nothing indicating it was intentionally fixed and nobody official has flagged it "complete".